# PIXI.Text as a hole but keeping stroke

Tags: pixi.js

I am trying to add text to a PIXI Application as a hole, cutting through the canvas showing what's underneath it, but need to keep the stroke around each letter. I am using a blendMode to cut the text through, but it removes the stroke as well. Is it even possible?

```
    //hacked clearing blendmode
    app.renderer.state.blendModes[20] = [0, 
        WebGLRenderingContext.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA];

    //Adding text
    var style = new PIXI.TextStyle({
        fontFamily: 'din-condensed',
        fontSize: '400px',
        fontWeight: 400,
        stroke: '#25556f',
        strokeThickness: 5
    });
    var invertedText = new PIXI.Text(text, style);

    invertedText.x = 0;
    invertedText.y = (height / 2) - ($(heading).height() / 2);
    invertedText.blendMode = 20;

    app.stage.addChild(invertedText);
```